change the padding between prefixIcon and the label in DropdownButtonFormField
This is simple signup form and I want to align the textfields and dropdowns (icons and labels) but I can't change the padding between the prefixIcon and the label,
This is simple signup form and I want to align the textfields and dropdowns (icons and labels) but I can't change the padding between the prefixIcon and the label,
Please advice, Thank you!!
my code for DropdownButtonFormField  is below

My code:
      CustomDropdownButtonFormField(
          hintText: "Gender",
          chosenValue: chosenGender,
          itemsList: genderList,
          prefixIcon: const FaIcon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.marsAndVenus,
            size: inputIconSize,
          ),
          suffixIcon: const FaIcon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.chevronDown,
            size: inputIconSize,
          ),
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              chosenGender = value;
            });
          }
      ),

The code for My CustomDropdownButtonFormField:
import 'package:app08/themes/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class CustomDropdownButtonFormField extends StatelessWidget {

  String? chosenValue='Role';
  final String? hintText;
  final List<String>? itemsList;
  final Function(dynamic value)? onChanged;
  final String? Function(String?)? validator;
  final Widget? prefixIcon;
  final Widget? suffixIcon;

  CustomDropdownButtonFormField({
    Key? key,
    this.chosenValue,
    this.hintText,
    this.itemsList,
    this.onChanged,
    this.validator,
    this.prefixIcon,
    this.suffixIcon,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final theme = Theme.of(context);

    var prefixIconFinal = (prefixIcon == null) ? null : Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, left: 15.0),
      child: prefixIcon,
    );

    var suffixIconFinal = (suffixIcon == null) ? null : Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, left: 10.0),
      child: suffixIcon,
    );

    return ButtonTheme(
        alignedDropdown: true,
        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
          hint: Text(hintText ?? ''),
          isExpanded: true,
          isDense: true,
          elevation: 8,

          iconSize: 0.0,
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_drop_down_sharp,
            size: 0,
            color: Colors.transparent,
          ),

          value: chosenValue,
          items: itemsList?.map((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),

          onChanged:onChanged,
          validator:validator,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            filled: true,
            isDense: true,

            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1, vertical: 15),
            // prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
            //   minWidth: 0,
            //   minHeight: 0,
            // ),

            counterText: "",
            prefixIcon: prefixIconFinal,
            //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),

            suffixIcon: suffixIconFinal,
            prefixIconColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => states.contains(MaterialState.focused) ? theme.primaryColor : theme.disabledColor),
            suffixIconColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => states.contains(MaterialState.focused) ? theme.primaryColor : theme.disabledColor),

            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(RADIUS),),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: theme.disabledColor),
            ),

            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(RADIUS),),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: theme.primaryColor, width: 1.0),
            ),

            errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(RADIUS),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: theme.colorScheme.error, width: 1.0),
            ),

            focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(RADIUS),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: theme.colorScheme.error, width: 1),
            ),

            disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(RADIUS),
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: theme.disabledColor, width: 1),
            ),

          ),

        ),
    );

  }
}

